# Google Admin SDK Directory API Call Hanging C#

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

I'm attempting to get all of the emails on my domain. I've set up everything in the developer console and given my service account the proper access in the admin console. It seems to be hanging when it gets to Execute and it's not giving any indication as to why.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyPathFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
     new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
     {
          Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser },
          User = "admin_account@gmail.com"
     }.FromCertificate(certificate));

DirectoryService service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
     {
          HttpClientInitializer = credential,
          ApplicationName = "app_name"
     });

var listReq = service.Users.List();
listReq.Domain = "domain";
Users allUsers = listReq.Execute();
```

Any ideas as to what might be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: issue tracker https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/590

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen that before. I'll downgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: If it does please let me know.  I am wondering if we are having an issue with the NuGet packages

Comment: This was indeed the issue. This was my first time using the google apis in a project, so I never would have caught this. I'll wait for them to fix this before I update my packages past 1.9.2. Thank you so much.

Comment: The main change in the new version is that the .dlls are strong name signed if you don't need that then there is no reason you cant use 1.9.2 until we deal with the nuget package issue.